# set new index for pandas DataFrame (interpolating?)

Tags: pandas, numpy, interpolation

I have a DataFrame where the index is NOT time.  I need to re-scale all of the values from an old index which is not equi-spaced, to a new index which has different limits and is equi-spaced.

The first and last values in the columns should stay as they are (although they will have the new, stretched index values assigned to them).

Example code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

index = np.asarray((2, 2.5, 3, 6, 7, 12, 15, 18, 20, 27))
x = np.sin(index / 10)

df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=index)
df.plot();

newindex = np.linspace(0, 29, 100)
```

How do I create a DataFrame where the index is `newindex` and the new `x` values are interpolated from the old `x` values?

The first new `x` value should be the same as the first old `x` value.  Ditto for the last `x` value.  That is, there should not be NaNs at the beginning and copies of the last old x repeated at the end.

The others should be interpolated to fit the new equi-spaced index.

I tried `df.interpolate()` but couldn't work out how to interpolate against the `newindex`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056399/interpolate-and-fill-pandas-dataframe-with-datetime-index

Comment: Yes: most existing answers (and the docs) have a date or time index but mine doesn't. Reindexing seems to be much easier if the index is dates or times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is works well:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def interp(df, new_index):
    """Return a new DataFrame with all columns values interpolated
    to the new_index values."""
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(index=new_index)
    df_out.index.name = df.index.name

    for colname, col in df.iteritems():
        df_out[colname] = np.interp(new_index, df.index, col)

    return df_out
```

Comment: interpolation of non-numeric types might require special attention

Answer (score 6):

I have adopted the following solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def reindex_and_interpolate(df, new_index):
    return df.reindex(df.index | new_index).interpolate(method='index', limit_direction='both').loc[new_index]

index = np.asarray((2, 2.5, 3, 6, 7, 12, 15, 18, 20, 27))
x = np.sin(index / 10)

df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=index)

newindex = pd.Float64Index(np.linspace(min(index)-5, max(index)+5, 50))

df_reindexed = reindex_and_interpolate(df, newindex)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df.index, df.values, color='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(df_reindexed.index, df_reindexed.values,  color='green', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `NameError: name 'merged_index' is not defined`

Comment: @blokeley fixed it

Comment: `df.index | new_index` can result in `FutureWarning: Index.__or__ operating as a set operation is deprecated` [#code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexes/base.py). `df.index.union(new_index)` would be better for newer versions of Pandas.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you're up against one of pandas limitations; it seems like you have limited choices for aligning your df to an arbitrary set of numbers (your `newindex`).

For example, your stated `newindex` only overlaps with the first and last numbers in `index`, so linear interpolation (rightly) interpolates a straight line between the start (2) and end (27) of your `index`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

index = np.asarray((2, 2.5, 3, 6, 7, 12, 15, 18, 20, 27))
x = np.sin(index / 10)

df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=index)

newindex = np.linspace(min(index), max(index), 100)

df_reindexed = df.reindex(index = newindex)
df_reindexed.interpolate(method = 'linear', inplace = True)

df.plot()
df_reindexed.plot()
```

[image: image1]

If you change `newindex` to provide more overlapping points with your original data set, interpolation works in a more expected manner:

```
newindex = np.linspace(min(index), max(index), 26)

df_reindexed = df.reindex(index = newindex)
df_reindexed.interpolate(method = 'linear', inplace = True)

df.plot()
df_reindexed.plot()
```

[image: image2]

There are other methods that do not require one to manually align the indices, but the resulting curve (while technically correct) is probably not what one wants:

```
newindex = np.linspace(min(index), max(index), 1000)

df_reindexed = df.reindex(index = newindex, method = 'ffill')

df.plot()
df_reindexed.plot()
```

[image: image3]

I looked at the pandas docs but I couldn't identify an easy solution.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-reindexing