# Recreating lost seconds + milliseconds in Pandas DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data from a gps unit which measures at 10 Hz but for some reason the vendor provides the timestamps up to minute precision. Thus, I end up with multiple replicates.

Is there a simple way to recreate the missing seconds and milliseconds assuming tat the order of the timestamps is correct and time starts at s = 0 and ms = 0?

Test case:

```
import pandas as pd

id_like = pd.date_range(start = '12:01:05', end = '12:04:05', freq='100ms')
ive_got = id_like.floor('1Min')
```

Comment: You can find the split the blanks using the known values by interpolation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I think your question may be a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056399/interpolate-and-fill-pandas-dataframe-with-datetime-index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpolate and fill pandas dataframe with datetime index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056399/interpolate-and-fill-pandas-dataframe-with-datetime-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can redefine your dataframe indexing using `pd.date_range`:

```
np.random.seed(0)
id_like = pd.date_range(start = '12:01:05', end = '12:04:05', freq='100ms')
ive_got = id_like.floor('1Min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(1801), index=ive_got)
```

Input dataframe print(df.head(10)):

```
                            0
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.548814
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.715189
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.602763
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.544883
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.423655
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.645894
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.437587
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.891773
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.963663
2018-11-13 12:01:00  0.383442
```

Redefined your index using `pd.date_range` with a frequency:

```
df.index = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='100ms')
```

Output print(df.head(10)):

```
                                0
2018-11-13 12:01:00.000  0.548814
2018-11-13 12:01:00.100  0.715189
2018-11-13 12:01:00.200  0.602763
2018-11-13 12:01:00.300  0.544883
2018-11-13 12:01:00.400  0.423655
2018-11-13 12:01:00.500  0.645894
2018-11-13 12:01:00.600  0.437587
2018-11-13 12:01:00.700  0.891773
2018-11-13 12:01:00.800  0.963663
2018-11-13 12:01:00.900  0.383442
```